# Springboot Mysql connecting to mysql remote host error: The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences[TLS13, TLS12

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

Using springboot mysql to connect to a remote database

```
spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://test.com/testdb?useSSL=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

throws an error

```
The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12]
```

using java openJDK 17.0.4 in Mac

tried to change the connection parameter using

```
spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://test.com/testdb?enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.3
```

throws another error

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

The same remote database can be connected using mysql client using -`-ssl --ssl-cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA`

How can i fix this error to connect my springboot app to this remote db.

Tried the solution given for java 11 but didnt work

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/tls-1-0-1-1-changes-in-openjdk-and-amazon-corretto/

Comment: Upgrade your MySQL so it supports TLSv1.2 or TLSv1.3, or alternatively change the security config of your JVM to allow TLSv1.0 (though that should be a last resort, as it is disabled for good reasons).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I tried the same in https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/tls-1-0-1-1-changes-in-openjdk-and-amazon-corretto/ to change the security config of my JVM to allow TLSv1.0, but didn't work for me